# Maven Embedded Glassfish plugin

Tags: maven-2, glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-embedded

I cannot seem to get the Maven Glassfish plugin working for the life of me:

```
<project>
  ...
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>glassfish-repository</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Glassfish</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>

        <configuration>
          <goalPrefix>glassfish</goalPrefix>
          <app>${artifactId}.war</app>
          <contextRoot>${context.root}</contextRoot>
          <port>${http.port}</port>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>  
</project>
```

When I run `mvn glassfish:run`, it is looking for a different plugin and cannot find it:

```
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-glassfish-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're not invoking the right plugin. It should be:

```
mvn embedded-glassfish:run
```

Actually, I'm using it like this: (with the same plugin repository you declared):

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <goalPrefix>glassfish</goalPrefix>
      <app>target/test.war</app>
      <port>8080</port>
      <contextRoot>test</contextRoot>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
         <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**Update:** Just in case, the fully qualified name of **this** plugin would be:

```
mvn org.glassfish:maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin:3.0:run
```

But using the short name works for me.

Comment: Pascal, thanks for your answer, but when I try to do that command above, I still get the plugin cannot be found:

[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found

Comment: @Walter Please post your entire pom because this works for me.

Comment: Pascal - sorry for the late reply, but I finally migrated over to Glassfish since it is one of the few Java EE 6 compatible containers.  This configuration works well.  I had to manually install the artifacts to get them working, but it runs now.

Answer (score 3):

@Walter White (can't/don't know how to reply to your comment so I'm answering instead):
I've read that scattered WAR's are [not fully supported by embedded GlassFish v3](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=GlassFishv3.1#section-GlassFishv3.1-Embedded).

Personally I'm anxiously awaiting v3.1 with Timer and MessageDriven support. Hopefully web service support will be included as well. Does anybody happen to have a clue about an ETA for v3.1?

PS: `mvn org.glassfish:maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin:3.0:run`
works for me. Will hook it up into a proper maven integration-test life cycle now.

Answer (score 0):

This problem outcome from fact that 2 differnt maven-glassfish plugins exist with the same name. Try to use

```
mvn org.glassfish:maven-glassfish-plugin:run
```

Detailed explanatation of this problem you can find [here](http://gregluck.com/blog/archives/2008/11/mvn-glassfishrun/).

Comment: I think that this blog post is outdated, the embedded plugin is maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin, not maven-glassfish-plugin. See http://blogs.sun.com/sirajg/entry/using_maven_plugin_for_v3

Answer (score 0):

see on github working example

mvn package embedded-glassfish:run

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <app>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</app>
                <port>8080</port>
                <contextRoot>${project.artifactId}</contextRoot>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.main</groupId>
                    <artifactId>simple-glassfish-api</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0-b79</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0-b83</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```